# How come my Adobe Illustrator file doesn't show up in After Effects?

Tags: adobe

I had created an Adobe Illustrator animation/illustration file with 9 layers each depicting a drawing that progresses.

I tried to import the file to Adobe After Effects successfully, but the image/drawing doesn't show up.

I have recorded a video of it here:

Anyone know why? What can I do to have the illustrations show up on the Effects screen?

Thank you,
Jae

Comment: Probably everything comes out black because both the background in After Effects and the outlines of your illustration are black. The white background in Illustrator actually is an alpha channel, so you're just putting black on black ... Try changing the color of either the outline of the illustration or the background in After Effects.

Comment: In the video above you did a black drawing on a transparent background did you not? So I'd guess AE is just showing you the black drawing over a black background. What happens when you change the background colour of the comp, or turn on transparency grid.

Answer (score 1):

Are you manually animating in illustrator and then bringing them in as individual frames in After Effects or are they independent assets?  After Effects treats Illustrator files as images that are displayed across multiple frames and the background is transparent.  You then animate them in After Effects itself by positioning and scaling and such.

If you have multiple layers in Illustrator, you also need to decide which layers are imported as your asset.  You can either flatten it or use individual layers when importing.

Comment: Ok, will try that. Thank you. I also recieved a reply stating that I had simply created a black screen. When I change the screen to transparent, the image/drawings show up:

http://youtu.be/krBytvYLjsA

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What worked was to save the AI file as CS3 compatible. Now it showes up again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue over and over again. I finally realized that my computer was so slow that it was showing me layers as if they were all black at first and after a couple of minutes they started showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is a really late answer but when you save as an .AI file, make sure you have the "Create PDF Compatible File" checked off. I ran into the same issue but once you check that box you should be good to go. [image]

Answer (score -1):

Its just the really bad implementation of the new code in CC. Adobe have released too many versions without adequate testing. They have made the suite rentalware so there is less pressure on them to produce high quality updates. As a result, their software is full of bugs.

Comment: It is true that Adobe CC quality has been very poor for a long time, but that's not a useful answer to the question.  It is at best a comment.